# Always getting "RETURN-FROM: no block named NIL is currently visible"

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp

```
(defun take-n (lst i)
  (setf newlst '())    
  (dotimes (n i)
    (setf newlst (cons (car lst) newlst))
    (print (cons (car lst) newlst))
    (setf lst (cdr lst)))
  (return newlst))
(print (take-n '(1 2 3) 2))
```

This gives me an error RETURN-FROM: no block named NIL is currently visible. I have tried moving the return statement around but I am not sure what it means.

Comment: Keep in mind `(setf lst (cdr lst))` actually modifies the original list

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Please indent your code in a Lisp way (this can be done automatically in many editors, like Emacs):

   ```
   (defun take-n (lst i)
     (setf newlst '())
     (dotimes (n i)
       (setf newlst (cons (car lst) newlst))
       (print (cons (car lst) newlst))
       (setf lst (cdr lst)))
     (return newlst))

   (print (take-n '(1 2 3) 2))
   ```
2. Do not `setf` a variable that was not declared beforehand: `(setf newlst '())` here refers to a hypothetical global variable `newlst`, but in a function you should strive to only have local state. You introduce variables in a block using `let`, as follows:

   ```
   (let ((new-list ()))
     ...
     ;; here you can setf new-list if you need
     ...)
   ```
3. `(setf newlst (cons (car lst) newlst))` can also be written `(push (car lst) newlst)`, but please do not use overly abbreviated names; you can use `list` and `new-list`, for example.
4. `return` makes a return to the enclosing block named `nil`, but here you have no such block. Instead, `defun` introduces an implicit block named like the function you define, i.e. you have implicitly:

   ```
   (block take-n
     ...)
   ```

   So if you wanted to return from it, you would need to do `(return-from take-n newlst)`.
5. BUT, you do not need to return since the last form being evaluated in the function is the value associated with the function call anyway.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use `RETURN`. In Lisp, the last expression in the function body is returned automatically, so just put the variable at the end of the function. Also, you should bind a local variable with `LET`, not assign a global variable.

```
(defun take-n (lst i)
  (let ((newlist '()))
    (dotimes (n i)
      (setf newlst (cons (car lst) newlst))
      (print (cons (car lst) newlst))
      (setf lst (cdr lst)))
    newlst))
```

The error you're getting is because `DEFUN` puts a named block around the function body, so you need to use `(return-from take-n newlst)`. `return` can only be used to return from an unnamed block (a block whose name is `NIL`); these are automatically put around looping macros like `DO`.

Comment: Also `(dotimes (n i newlst) <-- specify result in dotimes itself)`.  Very useful if you're not in an explicit or implicit `progn`.  `(if condition (dotimes (x y result) ...) (otherwise do this))`.